# Failed to find debug token

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am able to run the application on blackberry simulator but not able to run on device.I am running the app in debug mode. I am getting the warning like,

```
[INFO]    Target Z3-2be47f01 selected
[INFO]    Generating debug token
[INFO]    Error: The specified CSK password is not valid.
[INFO]    Populating application source
[INFO]    Parsing config.xml
[INFO]    Generating output files
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to /Users/admin/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[INFO]    Package created: /Users/admin/WebWorks Projects/Project6/platforms/blackberry10/build/simulator/bb10app.bar
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to /Users/admin/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[INFO]    Package created: /Users/admin/WebWorks Projects/Project6/platforms/blackberry10/build/device/bb10app.bar
[INFO]    BAR packaging complete
[INFO]    Sending request: INSTALL_AND_LAUNCH
[INFO]    Action: Install and Launch
[INFO]    File size: 2384586
[INFO]    Installing Project6.testDev_Project6___c8537c5d...
[INFO]    Processing 2384586 bytes
[INFO]    actual_dname::
[INFO]    actual_id::actual_version::result::failure 881 no debug token found
```

I am using BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK.I created a blackberry id & also generated a 'bbidtoken.csk file' & pasted in 'Research in Motion' path.

can anyone tell me that what is:

1. Keystore password.(how to get).
2. blackberry10debugtoken.bar.
3. How to install debug token in blackberry device.

..& finally how to run the app on blackberry device.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works on simulator is because simulator does not require debug token. Check [keytore password](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_2/testing_and_signing_setup.html).

[How to create and deploy debug token](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v1_0/running_your_app_on_a_device.html)

blackberry10debugtoken.bar - probably your debug token that you need to deploy to your device (look the link above, *blackberry-deploy*)

I'm a native developer so I don't know the details.

Answer (score 0):

The error is your keystore password. With the right password provided, WebWorks/Cordova will create and load a debugtoken on the device for you.

Your keystore password is the one you specified when you installed your signing keys. No one knows that password except you. You can recreate the token used for signing if you need to. Full instructions are posted here: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_2/testing_and_signing_setup.html#kba1382104438461